# What is the subject of this sentence? It is omitted

Tags: grammar, translation, subjects, context

> それらは必ず母屋から離れて、青葉の臭いや苔の臭いのしてくるような植え込みの影に設けてあり、 **廊下を伝わっていくのであるが、** その薄暗い光線の中にうずくまって、ほんのりや明るい障子の反射を受けながら瞑想にふけり、またはそう外の庭の景色を眺める気持ちは何とも言えない。

What is the meaning of the sentence written in bold here? Is the subject the light rays, the shadows or the bathroom itself? It's very confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can understand that this それら means "bathrooms" after reading a preceding sentence. So the subject is "people who go to the bathroom". When people walk along something, 伝わっていく is sometimes used such as 屋根の上を伝わっていく.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! It makes a lot of sense now.